# Can't push my own image to IBM Bluemix Registry

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, docker-registry, container-registry

I created a custom image with docker build, and want to push it to IBM Containers on Bluemix.
I did login with cf login and cf ic login, then I tagged the image, set the correct registry and namespace, and the push command worked only for a few layers and then it got stuck at a certain point (it froze at different MB values in the many tries I made).

```
docker push registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/mygcontainers/war3
```

The push refers to a repository [registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/mygcontainers/war3]

```
2d08e42cc27d: Mounted from mygcontainers/war3 
da4394905de1: Pushing [=======================>] 74.48 MB/159.3 MB
77f08abee8bf: Mounted from mygcontainers/war3
```

It has frozen with the Pushing message for hours.

PS: I tried on a Windows and Mac.
PS: I tried either US and UK endpoints. Same results.
PS: I did docker-machine restart also to check if it would change anything and works.

Comment: I think you have a dockerfile?  Instead of pushing a custom image, have you try to build directly on your IBM Container private registry instead?  i.e. cf ic build -t registry.ng.bluemix.net/<your registry>/<image name>.  More info: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_adding_ov.html#container_images_building

Answer (score 1):

In expect you already answered your question but, for others who might stumble upon similar issues, it is worth noting that the `push` will appear to get so far and then stop or fail if you weren't meticulously following the sequence of events detailed in [Pushing local images](https://new-console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_pulling.html) regarding the environment variables.

1. Check that `env | grep DOCKER` returns

   - *Nothing* for Docker for Mac; Docker for Windows;
     else do `unset ${!DOCKER_*}`
   - Otherwise what you expect for Linux docker server; or your current `docker-machine` machine
2. Tag your local image with the tag with which it will be known in your Bluemix registry. e.g.:
   `docker tag training/sinatra registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/my_namespace/new_sinatra`
3. Login to Bluemix 
   `cf login -u <my_bluemix_id> -o <my_organisation> -s <my_namespace>`
4. Login to IBM Containers 
   `cf ic login`
   Heed the directions *"Do not set the environment variables ..."*
5. *Now* the push should complete properly. e.g.:
   `docker push registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/my_namespace/new_sinatra`
6. Check that it is so:
   `cf ic images`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps for using `IBM Bluemix Container Registry` with the `container-registry` plugin for `bx`.  Installation instructions [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/registry_setup_cli_namespace.html#registry_setup_cli_namespace).

- `bx login` - login to Bluemix
- `bx cr namespace-list` - ensure you have a namespace created
- *Optional:* `bx cr namespace-add <my_namespace>` if required
- `bx cr login` - Log your local Docker client into the IBM Bluemix Container Registry
- `docker tag <localrepo>:<localtag> <bluemixregistryuri>/<namespace>/<repo>:<tag>`
- `docker push <bluemixregistryuri>/<namespace>/<repo>`

The registry URIs are: `registry.ng.bluemix.net`, `registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net` and `registry.eu-de.bluemix.net`.

Help for troubleshooting pushes can be found [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/troubleshoot/ts_index.html#ts_pushpull).